# In German Language, can someone refer to a country as "sie" or "er" in second person singular?

Tags: word-usage, gender, proper-noun

Example:

> Deutschland ist 357 375 km² groß.
>
> Er/sie hat 16 Bundesländer.

So my question is, what is the correct pronoun to use in that context, is it "er" or "sie" ?

Comment: to the reopen wish user: I see an accepted answer with upvotes, I see a duplicate nonetheless - why reopen? Where does it differ from the duplicate - the answer here is better/complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a country doesn't have an article, it's referred to as a neutral:

> Deutschland ist 357 357km² groß.
>
> Es hat 16 Bundesländer.

Otherwise it's referred to by the same gender as the article is:

> **Die** Mongolei ist riesig, aber **sie** hat nur wenige Einwohner.

Comment: One special case: *Die USA* are always plural -> "Die USA kämpfen mit Covid-19, sie haben die weltweit meisten Fälle."

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say if the countries gender is neuter, instead of "does not have article"? We can say "_das_ Deutschland, _es_ hat 16 Bundesländer", "_die_ Schweiz, _sie_ hat 26 Kantone", "_die_  USA, _sie_ bestehen aus 50 Einzelstaaten".

Comment: @miep Not quite that special: *die Malediven*, *die Seychellen*, etc. are always in plural too, and let's not forget *die VAE*.

Comment: @jay.sf "doesn't have an article" may be a bit inaccurate, but "das Deutschland" is at least highly unusual. However, there are regions where an article is used: *das Engadin*.

Comment: @RHa I might argue with you there, since  ["das Deutschland der * Jahre"](https://www.google.ch/search?ei=DbvYXszJG7ic1fAP_NiI-AM&q=%22das+Deutschland+der+*+Jahre%22&oq=%22das+Deutschland+der+*+Jahre%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB46CAghEBYQHRAeUJl9WIaFAWDwiAFoAHAAeACAAVaIAe4CkgEBNZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiMhMjh6OfpAhU4ThUIHXwsAj8Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) yields around 488,000,000 Google search results.

Comment: You should probably mention that the first sentence is not complete. It should be something like "Deutschland ist 357 375 km^2 groß."

Comment: @Roland danke/Thanks

Comment: @jay.sf That's not an article but a demonstrative pronoun. The wording "Das Deutschland der x-er Jahre" implies there are several Deutschlands (in different time periods) of which the writer points to a specific one (the one of the years starting with x).

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt You made a point. How would this affect the original issue that "has no article" is possibly inaccurate?

Comment: Somewhat academic, but the condition "has no article", taken literally, can be exact even in the face of your supposed counterexample, provided we consider "das" a demonstrative pronoun instead of an article.